# Inconvenientes en la Multiplicación de una Matriz por un Vector

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez pormedio de la presente deseo solicitarles su colaboración con lo siguiente, necesito realizar la multiplicación de una Matriz por un Vector en C++

Para lo cual tengo el siguiente código

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int M[i][j], V[j], R[i];  
    int tv=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de registros del vector: "<<endl;
    cin>>tv;
    for (int j=0; j<tv; j++)   //for(j=0; j<tv; j++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese el valor de cada registro del vector: "<<endl;
        cin>>V[j];
    }

    //Ingreso de filas y columnas de la matriz :
    int nf;
    cout<<"Ingrese el número de filas de la matriz: "<<endl;
    cin>> nf;
    int nc;
    cout<<"Ingrese el número de columnas de la matriz: "<<endl;
    cin>> nc;

    //Ingreso de valores de la matriz:

    cout<<"Ingrese los valores de la matriz: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<nf; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<nc; j++)
        {
            cout<<"fila: "<<i+1<<" "<<"columna: "<<j+1<<endl;
            cin>>M[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Operacion para hallar la matriz resultante: 
    for(i=0; i<nf; i++)
    {
        R[i]=0.0;
        for(j=0; j<nc; j++)
        {
            R[i] += M[i][j]*V[j];
            cout<< R[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al ingresar los siguientes valores, por ejemplo, una Matriz de 3 filas y 2 columnas, con los siguientes valores :

```
Matriz:                           Vector:
4   -2                            2         
1    2                            1
0   0
```

En vez de mostrarme el resultado que es un vector

```
6
4
0
```

Me muestra el siguiente resultado: 892200, cuando el resultado debería de ser  640.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: ¿Cual es el orden y valor de los inputs para replicar tu error?

Comment: Los inputs es ingresar el numero de registros del vector, que es el multiplicador y que se almacena en la variable tv (Tamaño del vector), Luego ingresamos el valor de cada registro del vector y lo almacenamos en el vector (V[j]),   Ahora procedemos a ingresar el número de filas de la matriz y lo almacenamos en la variable nf, lo mismo hacemos con las columnas y lo almacenamos en la variable nc , luego ingresamos  los valores delamatriz y los vamos almacenando en la misma matriz (M[i][j]), finalmente en R[i] realizamos el proceso  de calculo  R[i] += M[i][j]*V[j]; e imprimimos con cout<< R[i];

Comment: Variables sin inicializar que indican tamaños de arrays y que se espera que se auto-redimensionen solitos cuando asignes valor a las variables del tamaño.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que tienes un arreglo de enteros. La instrucción `R[i]=0.0` se puede simplificar cómo `R[i]=0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i;
int vector[i];
i = 10;
```

Este código esta mal por dos razones:

- `vector` se crea cuando aún no se conoce el valor de `i`. Lo que sucede realmente es que `i` tiene un valor basura (lo que hubiese en la posición de memoria donde ha aterrizado la variable) y ese es el valor que se usa para inicailizar `vector`. Que después cambies el valor de `i` no tiene efecto alguno ya que el tamaño de los arrays **es fijo** y **no se puede cambiar**
- Un array cuyo tamaño se basa en una variable se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y es una característica no soportada por el estándar de C++. Esto quiere decir que, dependiendo del compilador, tu código podría no compilar o, en caso de hacerlo, comportarse de forma diferente a la esperada.

Para valores dinámicos debes usar memoria dinámica:

```
int i;
i = 10;
int *vector = new int[i];
// ...
delete[] vector;
```

O mejor aún, usa contenedores de la STL:

```
std::vector<int> vector;
vector.push_back(1);
vector.push_back(2);

for( int elemento : vector)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando defines una formación<sup>1</sup> de valores, el tamaño debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, en tu caso las variables `i` y `j` contienen valores desconocidos en ese momento:

```
int i, j;
int M[i][j], V[j], R[i];
```

Pero aunque pudieras definir formaciones con valores variables, ten en cuenta que el código de C++ se ejecuta de arriba a abajo por lo que el tamaño de `M`, `V` y `R` **no cambiará retroactivamente al leer valores en `i` y `j`**… si eso sucediera ¿Qué crees que pasaría con tus formaciones al llegar a los bucles de lectura?:

```
cout<<"Ingrese los valores de la matriz: "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<nf; i++)
//  ^ <--- ¿Esto cambiaría el tamaño de M[i][j] y R[i]?
{
    for(j=0; j<nc; j++)
//      ^ <--- ¿Esto cambiaría el tamaño de M[i][j] y V[j]?
    {
        cout<<"fila: "<<i+1<<" "<<"columna: "<<j+1<<endl;
        cin>>M[i][j];
    }
}

//Operacion para hallar la matriz resultante: 
for(i=0; i<nf; i++)
//  ^ <--- ¿Esto cambiaría el tamaño de M[i][j] y R[i]?
{
    R[i]=0.0;
    for(j=0; j<nc; j++)
//      ^ <--- ¿Esto cambiaría el tamaño de M[i][j] y V[j]?
    {
        R[i] += M[i][j]*V[j];
        cout<< R[i];
    }
}
```

Olvida las formaciones, te aconsejo que las cambies por un contenedor estándar:

```
// Los alias de tipos hacen que el código sea más legible.
using fila_t = vector<int>;
using tabla_t = vector<fila_t>;

// Declara las variables cerca de donde las uses, eso hace el
// código más fácil de leer y menos propenso a errores.
int tv = 0;
cout << "Ingrese el numero de registros del vector:\n";
cin >> tv;

auto V = fila_t(tv); // Una fila de 'tv' elementos.

// Un bucle for de rango es más fácil de leer y escribir
// si usamos 'auto &' podremos modificar el elemento iterado.
for (auto &valor : V)
{
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de cada registro del vector:\n";
    cin >> valor;
}

//Ingreso de filas y columnas de la matriz :
int nf;
cout << "Ingrese el número de filas de la matriz:\n";
cin >> nf;

int nc;
cout << "Ingrese el número de columnas de la matriz:\n";
cin >> nc;

//Ingreso de valores de la matriz:
auto M = tabla_t(nf, fila_t(nc)); // Una tabla de 'nf' filas con 'nc' columnas

cout << "Ingrese los valores de la matriz:\n";
for (auto &fila : M)
{
    for (auto &valor : fila)
        cin >> valor;
}
```

Finalmente, estás imprimiendo todas las operaciones intermedias, en realidad te interesa el resultado no la parte parcial:

```
//Operacion para hallar la matriz resultante:
auto R = fila_t(nf);
for (int i = 0; i < nf; ++i)
{
    R[i] = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nc; ++j)
        R[i] += M[i][j] * V[j];
}

// Mostrar resultado
for (const auto &valor : R)
    cout << valor;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNNj9MwED3Xv2K0SDSh7LYUTm2aO4cKqRK9LCs0uE5x5Uwix4kEaP8YV35YGTtJv8gKRUpiz8zze/PGsizvpUHaH4@vNElT7xQkuqicVZin4rzXKOkKmwqhyUGOmqJY/BKjutK0B8JcVSVKBZXbLUW/nWmDXx2soC1OuDRd9kGH366jbXbqy/0ZruHQjNNlUTtIErj7SHurKgXKANW5sgUwMav2mtkWFS9MB7X4Qne@UBOkKQN5SKxdAVuGbI@JXBMvYTqFz4Rhy2ONXTNmdJUrckX1wFVZYSEKpa8bNLxYwDYWIxY@SKvNYSSJOzxR@5dZTy3k8/qZj5pOW6CgyjOq4AfIwtQ5oRcHzDFHZ/VPWLQdouyl7vz53benBbqsvm6Ox@jQ5P/RBuncAMrlrZigUt0UdY6s2ZFuEiLK3vbukIzP9oR48IeycadIFsRLOT5REgPkDU/F4OEt4wtzwwQsYN15O2C7z@DoC9Z9KpVFqZlUiRbhOxqD9sIxZlAbh@RUL3xzHkXK4pZN5H3QYez5k3hzYDLRHanNo35azR78lTglH1aceki46Zx4CPx8GkxWsObv4@HpzZZfHc8giztXObgWt4kvBrpTJkZWudqSv4PPx@NczMU78Z7fH8S9/52LGT9/AQ)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.